# Looping Through NSArray

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

This is suppose to play all the songs in the NSArray but it only plays one and stops. What am I doing wrong? The array contains a whole bunch of links to different .mp3 formatted songs.

```
NSArray *array = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

int nextTag = 1;
for (soundPath in array) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:soundPath];
    asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

    yourMediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    yourMediaPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    yourMediaPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 0;
    yourMediaPlayer.shouldAutoplay = FALSE;
    [yourMediaPlayer play];
    nextTag++;
}
```

Comment: 1.  Since you're using fast enumeration you don't need to keep track of the index, which is what I assume `nextTag` does.  2.  You're creating a new `MPMoviePlayerController` with each iteration and loading a new song, regardless of whether the song has finished playing.

Comment: @jcm So what you're saying is I should remove the MPMoviePlayerController from the loop and put it outside of it? If I do that then the music will still only play once.

Comment: Also, you're not waiting for the song to finish before loading the next one.

Comment: @jcm So what should I change up here then?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to get `MPMoviePlayerController` play a list of items use `AVQueuePlayer` instead.  It has a convenient `advanceToNextItem` method.

You can create a player already loaded with items (class `AVPlayerItem`) either with `initWithItems` or `queuePlayerWithItems`.  Then just call `play` on it (inherited from `AVPlayer`) and it should play the items one after the other.

See:

[AVQueuePlayer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVQueuePlayer/initWithItems%3a)

[AVPlayer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

[AVPlayerItem docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Should I just repeat the loop in the `advanceToNextItem`?